# MySQL statement inner join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, sentence

I have this SQL statement

```
SELECT
    locales.id_c,
    locales.name_p AS NombrePropietario,
    locales.surname1 AS PrimerApellido,
    locales.local_name AS Nombre_Local,
    locales.zona AS ZonaLiga,
    locales.id_m1 AS Maquina_1,
    maquinas.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina1,
    locales.id_m2 AS Maquina_2,
    maquinas.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina2,
    locales.id_m3 AS Maquina_3,
    locales.id_m4 AS Maquina_4
FROM locales
INNER JOIN maquinas
    ON locales.id_m1 = maquinas.id_m;
```

In this case, it only shows me the "Maquina_1" and "Tipo_de_Maquina1"

and need show "Maquina_2" and "Tipo_de_Maquina2", "Maquina_3" and "Tipo_de_Maquina3", etc.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Join the maqinas table multifold using table aliases:

```
SELECT
  l.id_c,
  l.name_p AS NombrePropietario,
  l.surname1 AS PrimerApellido,
  l.local_name AS Nombre_Local,
  l.zona AS ZonaLiga,
  l.id_m1 AS Maquina_1,
  m1.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina1,
  l.id_m2 AS Maquina_2,
  m2.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina2,
  l.id_m3 AS Maquina_3,
  m3.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina3,
  l.id_m4 AS Maquina_4,
  m4.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina4
FROM locales l
LEFT JOIN maquinas m1 ON l.id_m1 = m1.id_m
LEFT JOIN maquinas m2 ON l.id_m2 = m2.id_m
LEFT JOIN maquinas m3 ON l.id_m3 = m3.id_m
LEFT JOIN maquinas m4 ON l.id_m4 = m4.id_m
;
```

I'm using outer joins for the case that a record has no maquina 1, 2, 3 or 4. If every record always has all maquinas, you can switch to inner joins.

Anyway, you may want to consider another datamodel, in which you'd add a table `locale_maquina` and remove the single `id_m1` to `id_m4` from the `locales` table. This would make selecting the data easier and support a flexible number of maquinas linked to a location.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :-) Please see the remark I've just added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will value apply the advice you have recommended me, but im new in SQL world

Answer (score 0):

Your "Tipo_de_Maquina2" is wrong, because it will show the same value of "Tipo_de_Maquina1".

You should follow the same `INNER JOIN` logic of "Tipo_de_Maquina1", to get the other values of `tipo_m`.

```
SELECT
    locales.id_c,
    locales.name_p AS NombrePropietario,
    locales.surname1 AS PrimerApellido,
    locales.local_name AS Nombre_Local,
    locales.zona AS ZonaLiga,
    locales.id_m1 AS Maquina_1,
    m1.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina1,
    locales.id_m2 AS Maquina_2,
    m2.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina3,
    locales.id_m3 AS Maquina_3,
    m3.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina4,
    locales.id_m4 AS Maquina_4,
    m4.tipo_m AS Tipo_de_Maquina4
FROM locales
INNER JOIN maquinas AS m1
    ON locales.id_m1 = m1.id_m
INNER JOIN maquinas AS m2
    ON locales.id_m2 = m2.id_m
INNER JOIN maquinas AS m3
    ON locales.id_m3 = m3.id_m
INNER JOIN maquinas AS m4
    ON locales.id_m4 = m4.id_m;
```